# Detecting if a button was clicked from another class

Tags: c#, winforms, button, if-statement, detect

I am looking for a way to detect if a button was pressed in C#. For example:

```
    private void webBrowser1_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)        {

       if (button1Clicked == true)
       {
          MessageBox.Show("Button 1 was clicked"); 
       }
    }
```

Thank you for looking.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more. Whats your program in? browser, java, desktop,....

Comment: Revised - I knew I forgot to state something.

Comment: e.ClickedElement or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just use a static variable and change the state of this static variable and check it. For instance;

```
public static bool button1Clicked;
```